# Alternative ways to deploy code to Openshift

Tags: openshift, travis-ci

I am trying to setup Travis CI to deploy my repository to Openshift on a successful build. Is there a way to deploy a repository besides using Git?

Comment: No, Openshift uses git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git is the official mechanism for how your code is update, however depending on the type of application that you are deploying you may not need to deploy your entire code base.

For example Java application (war, ear, etc) can be deployed to JBoss or Tomcat servers, by simply taking the built application and checking it into the OpenShift git repositories, webapps or deploy directories.

An alternative to this (and it will be unsupported), is to scp your application to the gear using the SSH key. However any time the application is moved or updated (with git) this content stands a good chance of getting deleted(cleaned), by the gear.

Comment: Documentation on application Deployments https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/OpenShift_Online/2.0/html-single/User_Guide/index.html#sect-OpenShift-User_Guide-Deploying_Applications

Answer (score 0):

We're working on direct binary deploys ("push") and "pull" style deploys (Openshift downloads a binary for you.  The design/process is described here:

https://github.com/openshift/openshift-pep/blob/master/openshift-pep-006-deploy.md

Answer (score 0):

You can do a SCP to the app-root/dependencies/jbossews/webapps directory direcly. I was able to do that successfully and have the app working. Here is the [link](https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202399740-How-to-deploy-pre-compiled-java-applications-WAR-and-EAR-files-onto-your-OpenShift-gear-using-the-java-cartridges)

Here is the code which I had in the after_success blck

> after_success:
>   - sudo apt-get -y install sshpass
>   - openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_8544f7cb7a3c_key -iv $encrypted_8544f7cb7a3c_iv
>       -in id_rsa.enc -out ~/id_rsa_dpl -d
>   - chmod 600  ~/id_rsa_dpl
>   - sshpass scp -i ~/id_rsa_dpl webapps/ROOT.war $DEPLOY_HOST:$DEPLOY_PATH

Hope this helps